# AutoHotkey Remapping Keys

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap a couple of keys using a program called AutoHotkey. I don't really have any coding experience but I took a shot at it and ended up unsurprisingly sucking at it haha. Was wondering if anybody could help with my issue

I wanted to remap my left ctrl and l key to send the tilde key (` key next to the 1), and my left ctrl and left shift button to the esc key. I'm trying to use these remapped keybindings in some games, and I've heard that there's some problems using AHK with video games in general. Tried to remedy this problem using the commands AHK help recommended, like SendPlay, or SendMode, Play.

So far this is the code I've written that's ended trying to solve this:

```
#SingleInstance force

^l::SendMode, Play {`}
{LShift}{LCtrl}::SendMode, Play {Esc}
```

Would appreciate any help with this...thanks!

Comment: You might consider using the Microsoft Power Toys instead.  They can do keyboard remapping at a low level.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I was looking for... thanks Tim!

Answer (score 0):

```
<^l::SendPlay ``
LShift & LControl::SendPlay {Escape}
```

You shouldn't use a hotkey made of two modifier keys though.

Comment: Hmm... how about ^k::SendMode, Play {Esc}?

Comment: @Ventiwater, this isn't how you use [SendMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm).

Comment: @Ventiwater, just use [the regular `Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm). It is likely what you are actually looking for. I highly recommend you read the [Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for a 10 minute guide to the basics of AHK.